# hed__Application_Status__c is not visible in Process Builder

Tags: salesforce

We need to update a process builder.

To do the same, we cloned the existing process builder.

The process builder has a criteria on *Application Status*(API name: *hed__Application_Status__c*) field.

When I click on that criteria, get the below message:

[image]

My user profile is System Administrator. The System Administrator has access to all fields of Application:

[image]

When I try to find the field in the object in process builder, not able to find the same:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

FLS was not there for System Administrator for Application Status field.

After adding that, I am not seeing the error.